# CSS3 pie not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter, css3pie

I have implemented the css3pie in view like this:

```
.abc{
        behavior: url("./assets/../../PIE.htc");
        background-color: yellow;
        border: 0px solid;
        border-radius: 17px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #999999;

    }
```

this is not working for me even i edit the .htaccess in /public_html/.htaccess to:

```
CheckSpelling On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Thank you very much for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess has been set incorrect level .htaccess and i have fixed it.

Need to set .htaccess level:

**public_html/.htaccess**

**public_html/CSS3PIE/.htaccess**

Answer (score 0):

Must be the PATH problem.

Have you tried directly navigating to the url (in the address bar) to make sure you can access it? Try putting it in the same directory as your CSS file to be sure.

A lot of elements need position:relative or zoom:1 when using PIE in order to behave in IE, make sure you check the known issues page and play around until you get it to work.

Comment: even i put the PIE.htc and PIE.php in the same directory of view and adding position:relative or zoom:1 in the css of view, it is still not working for me when i am using IE 8 to browse the page.